# Http to https redirect for Youtrack that is behind ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, https, ssl-certificate, amazon-elb

I am configuring Youtrack issue tracker that resides on EC2 instance. I purchased SSL certificate using AWS Certificate Manager. When I realized that I can't download it I decided to assign it to an Elastic Load Balancer (ELB) to handle https, behind ELB it sends http inside of VPC.
[image]

I'm trying to force users to use HTTPS when they're connecting via HTTP.
If I disable HTTP listener on ELB then it works well via HTTPS but it's not what I want.

The only option I haven't tried yet is to configure 301 redirect on Jetty that is Eclipse's Java-based web server that is used in Youtrack.

Any idea how to achieve it using AWS services?

Comment: You have to do this in Jetty, like you mentioned. AWS doesn't do this for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performing a 301 Redirect from HTTP to HTTPS is not supported by ELB.

However, you can do this using CloudFront. Using CloudFront, you can:

1. Use the same SSL certificate that you're already using with ELB.
2. The connection from CloudFront to ELB can be:

   - HTTPS to ELB using the same certificate,
   - HTTP to ELB, or
   - HTTP directly to your EC2 instance
3. CloudFront can be configured to accept HTTP connections and 301 redirect them to HTTPS.